# cannot access/not found the file /run/gunicorn.sock while bulding jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, deployment, pipeline, local

i am trying to uild a jenkins pipeline for deploying my django application in my locacalhost. i have set up my django virtualenv in envsetup.sh. and for gunicorn i have a file gunicorn.sh with the folling bash script

```
gunicorn.sh

#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
# Activate the virtual environment
source "$SCRIPT_DIR/myenv/bin/activate"
echo "$SCRIPT_DIR"
# Navigate to your Django project directory
cd "$SCRIPT_DIR/backEnd"

# Apply database migrations
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate

# Navigate back to the main directory
cd "$SCRIPT_DIR"
current_directory=$(pwd)
echo "Curreent Directory :$current_directory"

# Copy the Gunicorn socket and service unit files to the systemd directory
sudo cp -f "$SCRIPT_DIR/gunicorn.socket" /etc/systemd/system/   
sudo cp -f "$SCRIPT_DIR/gunicorn.service" /etc/systemd/system/ 
pip list

# Reload systemd to pick up the new unit files
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

# Start and enable the Gunicorn socket
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket

echo '--------------------start gunicorn socket------------------------------'
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket

# Check the status of the Gunicorn socket
echo '--------------------status gunicorn socket------------------------------'
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket

# Start and enable the Gunicorn service
echo '--------------------enable gunicorn------------------------------'
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn

echo '--------------------start gunicorn------------------------------'
sudo systemctl start gunicorn

echo '--------------------restart gunicorn------------------------------'
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.socket


echo '--------------------restart gunicorn------------------------------'
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn



echo "Gunicorn has started."

# Display the contents of the Gunicorn socket file
echo '--------------------display gunicorn socket file content -----------------------------'
file ./gunicorn.socket

# Display Gunicorn socket logs
echo '--------------------display gunicorn socket log-----------------------------'
sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.socket

sudo -u jenkins ls -l /var/run/gunicorn.sock

sudo chown jenkins:jenkins /var/run/gunicorn.sock

sudo chmod 660 /var/run/gunicorn.sock

ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock

echo "----------------------TESTING GUNICORN----------------"
# Test the Gunicorn server using curl  , u dont need to specify ip when using unix-socket 
curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock http:/   # root url
    
# Display the status of the Gunicorn service
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

```
gunicorn.service    
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/django-ci-cd/backEnd
ExecStart=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/django-ci-cd/myenv/bin/gunicorn \
  --access-logfile /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/django-ci-cd/logs/access.log \
  --error-logfile /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/django-ci-cd/logs/error.log \
  --workers 3 \
  --bind unix:/var/run/gunicorn.sock \
  --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=event_management.settings \
  event_management.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Socket]
ListenStream=gunicorn.sock  # Using relative path to the socket
```

```
gunicorn.socket

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

when i use my terminal as jenkins user i can access /run/gunicorn.sock file but when i list the run folder file from bash script it does not show the gunicorn.sock file.
i want curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock http:/    to display my django  home page